# How to add hyperlinks to local files in Numbers?

Tags: finder, numbers, iwork, path, url

How do I add a hyperlink to a local file?

I know how to add a hyperlink to a website, so I tried something like `file:///Users/MyUser/Documents/Invoices/Some%20Stuff.pdf`

However, adding this path to the hyperlink won't make Numbers open the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to create a link to a different file or different sheet within the same Numbers file?

Comment: I want to add a link to a pdf in finder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Numbers cannot link to a non-Numbers local document other than an email.

Numbers can create a link to a webpage, or to a sheet (in Numbers, a "sheet" is a tab within a single spreadsheet), or to a specific email. Numbers cannot, however, create a link to other types of files. [This Apple Numbers page](https://support.apple.com/guide/numbers/link-a-webpage-email-sheet-numbers-mac-tan38c68b48b/mac) contains this text:

> **Link to a webpage, email, or sheet in Numbers on Mac**
>
> You can turn any text into a link that opens another sheet in the spreadsheet or opens a webpage or email message.
> Numbers automatically detects valid web addresses (URLs) and email addresses and styles them (for example, with an underline or different color) to indicate that they’re active links. You can edit these links or deactivate them so that they appear and behave as normal text. If you don’t want Numbers to automatically detect links, you can turn off automatic link formatting.

The same text (and same limitation as to linked filed types) appears in Numbers on-line help, and in the Menu Bar at Numbers > Format > Add Link.

Answer (score 0):

If numbers app is not expecting a filesystem link, i.e. it is not coded to except such cases, it will not open the file.

Compare this with Sublime's, VSCode's or Xcode hyperlink feature that you can follow by double clicking or command-clicking. They are programmed to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Shortcuts (I use it with iCloud to make it working on iOS as well)

1. Add `Open File` action
2. Add `Get File from Folder` action
3. Set your main directory (iCloud Drive in my case)
4. as path use `Shortcut Input`
5. Set only `Text` type as allowed input

Now you can use it with following pattern:
`shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=[my_shortcut]&input=[my_path]`

Note: you for file path with spaces or subfolders (`/`) you need to encode your url (https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)
e.g. for `dir/my file.txt` you will get `dir%2Fmy%20file.txt`

**Example**

For file `iCloud Drive/dir/my file.txt` use following URL to open it from Numbers or any other app/browser:

`shortcuts://run-shortcut?name=open_file&input=dir%2Fmy%20file.txt`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the [Hookmark app](https://hookproductivity.com), you can create a hyperlink to any file (protocol is hook://, they look like this: hook://file/...) (and to emails and all kinds of resources). You can paste them in Numbers. Numbers will honor that link, meaning you can click on the link and macOS will open the file (or reveal it in Finder, depending on your Hookmark General setting).

hook://file/... links have the advantage that they are adaptive, meaning even if you rename or move the file around the links will still work. They work a bit like Finder aliases; but better since aliases don't have a URL format, and Hookmark's file links deal with a lot of edge cases that aliases can't handle (e.g., you can link to files in volumes, shared folders [dropbox , etc.] and version control repositories [git, SVN, etc] that get remounted/moved elsewhere). This is [explained here](https://hookproductivity.com/help/hook-window/make-hook-file/). Plus the links are shareable , others can use them as long as they install Hookmark (the free Basic version can open links). In contrast you can't just email someone an alias and expect great results.

This is zero config, hence easier than Shortcuts-based solution; as long as you have Hookmark.

Full disclosure, I'm a co-founder of CogSci Apps Corp. which makes Hookmark.